# Regarding jquery select tag

Tags: jquery, html, struts2

I'm using struts2 and jQuery.

Following is my code written in JSP:

```
<s:select o name="mfgDimensions" list="{'Product','Station','Test','AssemblyLine','Operator','Debug Mode'}" multiple="true" headerKey="" headerValue="Manufacturing Dimensions" size="3"/>
```

I want when user will going to select header value (i.e in my case "Manufacturing Dimensions") the value will not be get selectable...

can it be possible with jquery or any other way??

Thanks
kris

Comment: Can you view-source on the generated HTML page and post the relevant HTML in your question above (you'll need to code-format it with the '{}' button.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <s:select id="dimension" name="mfgDimensions" list="{'Product','Station','Test','AssemblyLine','Operator','Debug Mode'}" multiple="true" headerKey="" headerValue="Manufacturing Dimensions" size="3"/
onchange="check_value(this.value)"/>


function check_value(value){
if(value=="Manufacturing Dimensions")
  document.getElementById("dimension').value='';
}
```

Comment: still that header value is selectable.. anyway Thanks anu